# Changing CSS on navbar depending on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a site using a Bootstrap 3 navbar and am trying to change the background colour from transparent to solid when the user scrolls to a certain point on the site.

I have written the following the code although had no luck in getting it to work. Thanks in advance.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Mobile Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="nav-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand logo" href=""><img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Flock+ Logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <!-- Navigation Links -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">COURSES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PRICING</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ACCOUNT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar { background-color:#101010; border:none; }
#logo { width:45px; height:auto; }
.navbar-right li a { color:#e5e5e5; font-family:headings; font-size:14px; }
ul.navbar-right li a:hover { color:#e5e5e5; text-decoration: none; background-color:transparent; }
ul.navbar-right li a:visited { color:#e5e5e5; text-decoration:none; }

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar { background-color: transparent; border:none; transition:0.8s; }
    .nav-scrolled { background-color:#181818; transition:0.8s; }
    .navbar-right li a { letter-spacing:3px; }
}
```

**JS:**

```
// Change nav on scroll
$(function() {
    var header = $(".navbar");

    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 200) {
            header.addClass("nav-scrolled");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("nav-scrolled");
        }
    })
});
```

**ALT:**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So is the class being applied? Did you inspect and see what is overriding the color?

Comment: It isn't being applied no, if I remove the transparent background on .navbar however then the solid colour is applied with the transition. (At the top of the page, not on scroll)

Comment: It works for me, maybe you were testing on a window that was too small so the `.nav-scrolled` wasn't being applied. Remove the media query to test it.

Comment: @Matt.Hamer5 What was the problem?

Comment: So maybe the transparent css color has a css rule that overrides the new class you just added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your exact code, minus the media query around the css, to show you that it works. I also added extra height to the nav so you can actually scroll.

If your code isn't working on your computer, you may not be referencing files properly.

```js
// Change nav on scroll
$(function() {
    var header = $(".navbar");

    $(window).scroll(function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 200) {
            header.addClass("nav-scrolled");
        } else {
            header.removeClass("nav-scrolled");
        }
    })
});
```

```css
.navbar { background-color:#101010; border:none; height: 200vh}
#logo { width:45px; height:auto; }
.navbar-right li a { color:#e5e5e5; font-family:headings; font-size:14px; }
ul.navbar-right li a:hover { color:#e5e5e5; text-decoration: none; background-color:transparent; }
ul.navbar-right li a:visited { color:#e5e5e5; text-decoration:none; }


    .navbar { background-color: transparent; border:none; transition:0.8s; }
    .nav-scrolled { background-color:#181818; transition:0.8s; }
    .navbar-right li a { letter-spacing:3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" id="nav">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <!-- Mobile Hamburger -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="nav-icon" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand logo" href=""><img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="Flock+ Logo"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <!-- Navigation Links -->
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">COURSES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PRICING</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ACCOUNT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```